# About led connection

Tags: led

I have 20 pieces  3v 0.5w 150mA 5730 smd led chips and a 3.7v 2600mAh li-ion battery. 
I want connect 20 pieces led s in parallel and use the battery as a power source. Thus I decide to make an emergency bulb. Using 5ohm resistor in every connection. 
How efficient it will be? ? Or is there any problem? ?

Comment: Expect flaming resistors.

Comment: 0.6v/0.15 = 4 Ohms 0.09W per LED using 1/4W and for 10W you need big heatsink 10sqin min or 65sq.cm. Surface area and with 9.6Wh ideal expect 1h life down to dim

Comment: If I want to use round heatsink. . Then what will be it's diameter? And how do I calculate the heatsink requirement?

Comment: Pi (D/2) squared = area if smooth and round aluminum substrate to LED over copper pads

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist if these mid power LEDs have decent efficacy and the LEDs are not too close to one another (e.g. a 10" x 1" strip) they will not need a heatsink.  I would recommend using Samsung LM301B LEDs with about 220 lm/W efficacy.  I put 45 of them on a 4" x 4" PCB and no heatsink is required a 150 mA.

Comment: The 10x1” aluminum or copper strip is a heatsink  and 4x4 is 16 sq.in. But great LEDs

Comment: LM301B’s are typically Vf=2.65+1.2*If. Which for a 0.3W class LED so 1.2Ohm *0.3W=k=0.36 is good but at 150mA only 150 lumens /watt (nom)

Comment: I can't understand the calculation of heatsink. . It is too tough to put a large heatsink into the emergency led bulb. .. so what is the efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

It is going to work fairly well.  You may want to use two batteries in parallel. You may want to drop the resistor value below 5Ω so the LED is brighter as the battery discharges.

Most Li-ion are 3.6V nominal and many vendors of off brand batteries claim they are 3.7V.  They charge to 4.2V buy quickly drop to below 4V.

The closest common resistor to 5Ω is 5.1Ω.

At 3.6V with a 5.1Ω current limiting resistor the current is 120 mA, power dissipation is 432 mW, and efficiency is 83.3%.

[image]

x20 LEDs = 2400 mA

---

A popular Li-ion is the [Panasonic NCR18650](https://engineering.tamu.edu/media/4247819/ds-battery-panasonic-18650ncr.pdf)

You are looking at about a 1C discharge which is shown in the datasheet in the Discharge Characteristics (by rate of discharge) as the green curve.

[image]

As the battery discharges the voltage tapers off and the efficiency improves.

When the battery is at 3.1v, approaching its cutoff voltage, the the efficiency is at 96.8%.  The bad news is current drops to about 20 mA.

[image]

---

I would use a 4.3Ω which would slightly exceed the 150 mA for the first few minutes after a fresh charge but would remain brighter longer. A 4.7 is the maximum I would use.  A 5.1Ω will work okay.

You could use a boost CC driver with a 30V output and wire the LEDs in 10 sets of 2 parallel LEDs in series.

I do not use boost converters or buy off the shelf.
These circuits are made for powering mobile device LEDs and screens.

What the boost converter will do for you is give you consistent brightness from fresh charge to cutoff. It may not give you longer battery life.
The resistors are fairly efficient.  The boost driver will keep the output power constant where the batteries will discharge and lower the output power (and brightness).

[TPS61500 3-A Boost Converter](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps61500.pdf)
[Microchip MIC2299](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/mic2299.pdf)

If you were to search for an off the shelf use the search term "boost step up constant current"
You need 3A (2.4 Amp minimum) with 3V or less input.

Comment: Could you explain your math? 20 * 120 mA is 2.4 A but not 1200 A. 1200 mA is wrong too, but 2400 mA is correct too.

Comment: @MdMubinArsenal I added some recommendations but doubt they will help much, I only design step down regulators.  It is very common to boost a Li-ion battery to 30+ volts in mobile battery powered devices.

Answer (score 0):

Well, let's see if there's a problem.

20LEDs at 150mA each, in parallel.

Current adds in parallel circuits, so you will need to supply about 3 amperes of current.

Your battery is rated for 2600mAh.  That's 2.6Ah.  So, on the face of it, not enough capacity for an hour.

The voltage drops while the battery discharges.  It won't drop below 3V until almost the end, so that should be okay.

You are discharging the battery at a relatively high rate.  Batteries deliver less than their rated capacity under heavy load.

So, you will get far less than an hour out of your light.

---

Other problems:

1. Current limiting.

If you just connect an LED to a voltage source with a voltage higher than the forward voltage of the LED, then the LED becomes the next best thing to a short circuit.  It will draw as much current as the battery will deliver.  The LED will heat up and burn out.  Current limiting can be done with a linear regulator, a switching regulator, or a series resistor.  The linear regulator and the series resitor operate by throwing away energy as heat.  Switching regulators are harder to design and build.

2. Current sharing.

If you connect two LEDs in parallel, then limit the current to them as a pair, then your LEDs must be perfectly matched.  Companies who make LED lights can buy batches of good quality, matched LEDs.  You can't.  If the LEDs aren't matched, then one will have a lower forward voltage than the other.  The one with the lower forward voltage will light up brighter than the other.  If you are really unlucky, one will draw all the current intended for two and burnout - leaving the other LED drawing the current intended for two, so it burns out also.

3. Efficiency

The easiest way to limit current is to put a resistor in series with every LED. That isn't very efficient, though.  Take worst case:  3.7V supply, 3.0V LED. You must drop 0.7V to bring the voltage down to what the LED expects.  At 150mA, that's 0.1 watts of power.  Against the power to the LED of 0.45 watts.  So, like 25% of the energy in the battery is being thrown away heating the resistors.  That shortens your run time even more.

A linear regulator would do the same, and lose a little more for its own operation.  So, best case about the same as using a series resistor.

A switching regulator turns the current on and off very quickly.  A filter then smooths this to DC.  It measures the current through the LED, and switches on a little longer if more current is needed, or off a little longer if less current is needed.  It switches on and off thousands of times per second.  This kind of regulator can be as much as 90% efficient, but is more complicated to build.

---

Back up and consider how much light you really need.

If those 20 LEDs are really what you need, then you need to consider how long the light has to ... light.

If you need more than about half an hour, then that battery won't do.  You'll need one with more capacity.

If that battery is all you've got, but you need the light on for longer, then you will have to reduce the load - that's less current to the LEDs and/or fewer LEDs.

Comment: The questioner did write about a current limiting resistor for each LED: "Using 5ohm resistor in every connection."